# RoundMask gives exception when image of specific size is used

Tags: codenameone

I have got a quite interesting problem here. While using round Mask, it was working all fine but i found a issue in my device. So I checked in the simulator (iOS 6) and found that if I use image of size 480 * 480 or 485 * 485, it gives "Mask and image sizes don't match" error. I change the size to 470 * 470 and 500 * 500, it works perfectly. Moreover 480*475 works fine too. Square img with specific sizes are giving the errors eg:694*694, 690*690 gives error. The display width of the simulator shows 750 in the output.

```
System.out.println("width " + Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()); //output = 750
if (profile_img != null && !"".equals(profile_img)) {
    Image roundMask = Image.createImage(placeholderForProfile.getWidth(), placeholderForProfile.getHeight(), 0xff000000);
    roundMask = roundMask.scaledWidth(screenWidth / 3);
    Graphics gr = roundMask.getGraphics();
    gr.setColor(0xffffff);
    gr.fillArc(0, 0, placeholderForProfile.getWidth(), placeholderForProfile.getHeight(), 0, 360);

    URLImage.ImageAdapter ada = URLImage.createMaskAdapter(roundMask);

    AllUrl au = new AllUrl();
    Image getProfileImage = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholderForProfile, "profile.png",
            au.profileImgUrl + profile_img, ada);
    profileImg.setIcon(getProfileImage);
}
```

Error in simulator:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mask and image sizes don't match
[EDT] 0:8:44,805 - Exception in AppName version 1.01
[EDT] 0:8:44,805 - OS ios
[EDT] 0:8:44,805 - Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mask and image sizes don't match
[EDT] 0:8:44,805 - Current Form Profile
[EDT] 0:8:44,805 - Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Mask and image sizes don't match
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.applyMask(Image.java:279)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$3.postProcess(URLImage.java:180)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$ScaleToFill.adaptImage(URLImage.java:119)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$DownloadCompleted.actionPerformed(URLImage.java:214)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:459)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.access$100(EventDispatcher.java:45)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher$CallbackClass.run(EventDispatcher.java:95)
Rendering frame took too long 166 milliseconds
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1151)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1095)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:996)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mask and image sizes don't match
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.applyMask(Image.java:279)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$3.postProcess(URLImage.java:180)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$ScaleToFill.adaptImage(URLImage.java:119)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$DownloadCompleted.actionPerformed(URLImage.java:214)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:459)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.access$100(EventDispatcher.java:45)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher$CallbackClass.run(EventDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1151)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1095)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:996)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Answer (score 0):

The mask and the placeholder should match in size exactly. You invoke `scaled` on the mask which might have no effect if the sizes are already the same but will fail badly if they aren't.

Comment: Without scaling the mask, it was giving same error so i kept it. I have kept placeholder width and height in roundMask, so the sizes must be same, isn't it? The problem is it is giving error only on specific sized images as I have mentioned above. In all other with different sizes, it is working great.

Comment: I explained why it can fail for specific sizes. That exception is thrown here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Image.java#L278-L280 indicating that mask size != image size